# Show Multiple Item Details in TextView not only Sinlge

Tags: android

Getting value for only single Item in TextView from CartActivity, but want to fetch detail for all Item(s) placed in Cart

Like: I have 4 items in Cart, but once i am trying to show these item details in another activity, so here i am only getting single item detail **(only for 4th Item, not for all fours)** why?

**CODE:**

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Session.sItem_Detail.size(); i++) {

String title=Constants.sItem_Detail.get(i).get(
    ProductInformationActivity.KEY_TITLE);

String qty=Constants.sItem_Detail.get(i).get(
    ProductInformationActivity.KEY_QTY);

String cost=Constants.sItem_Detail.get(i).get(
    ProductInformationActivity.KEY_COST);


 textDetails =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDetails);
 textDetails.setText("(Title:" +title + "(Qty:" + qty + ")" + "(Cost:" + "Rs." + cost + ")");



  public class Session {
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sItem_Detail = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
```

So here is my question, how can i get item details for all items stored in Cart, not just for one..

Comment: in intent pass all value from current activity to another activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

use `append(charctersequence)` instead of `setText(charctersequence)`

```
textDetails.append("(Title:" +title + "(Qty:" + qty + ")" + "(Cost:" + "Rs." + cost + ")"+"\n");
```